# .Net how can i do this? (work with timers)

Tags: c#, .net, timer

There is WinForms application.
Its functionality (for example) - Ping machines in the corporate domain.
Let's imagine, that a user has created two objects in the application for the ping - Comp1 and Comp2.
Most main feature - the program should give the user a choice - intverval through what kind of computer you need to ping.
For example, the availability of Comp1 user wants to monitor every minute and Comp2 availability - every 15 minutes.
How can i implement it on .NET? Create for each new Comp [number] Timer object programmatically?

Maybe someone has already encountered such a challenge, a big request help me..

Comment: Use dispatch timer for your scenario.

Comment: Please read [Ask].  Your title *screams* please downvote me

Comment: Pluonix, thank you! I will consider it next time

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if Comp2 is accessible (network-wise) from Comp1, you could run the following code on Comp1

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
PingReply reply = new Ping().Send(Comp1IP);
return reply.Status == IPStatus.Success
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea - to create only one universal timer tmrTimer, it will be running once a minute.
Application will keep in database / memory for each Comp [number] refresh interval and time of last ping.
During every minute trip tmrTimer_Tick will be check on all the data for each of the Comp [number].
And if the difference (current time - the last ping Comp [number])> than the desired refresh interval for this Comp [number] - application will pings Comp [number], updating the last ping the current time for him ...

Is not it too easy?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 2 timers.

Make a winform, allow the user to choose the time interval by using NumericUpDown controls, or find a better way.

Set the interval at the specified milliseconds (60000 = 1 minute, 900000 = 15 mins) Tick event will launch the ping through

**- Ping class:**

[Ping class on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 public static int GetPing(string ip, int timeout)
    {
        int p = -1;
        using (Ping ping = new Ping())
        {
                PingReply reply = ping.Send(_ip, timeout);
                if (reply != null)
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        p = Convert.ToInt32(reply.RoundtripTime);
        }
        return p;
    }
```

**-Command prompt**

This is how you send the command through cmd, so you won't use the .net framwework, but the windows built in tool:

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "timeout 60 & ping 127.0.0.1";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

The timeout 60 will wait 60 seconds and then it will ping. Then you will see onscreen if the ping has failed or not

To use only a single timer, set the tick to one minute and in the tick increase a counter variable. Every  tick (1 minute) it will ping comp1, when the modulus of the counter for 15 is 0 (counter % 15 == 0) you will ping comp2